# Correct way to Use " * " as a placeholder for any string in a path

Tags: console, placeholder

I know that I can use " * " as a placeholder for any string, for example in Powershell. If I remember right, I could use it too in VB, but I cannot remember the correct way of it's Usage. 
Also my brother Google couldn't help me.

My Code:

`My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Documents\*_Puliafito.docx", "C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Documents\Schule\Puliafito\")`

It should move any Document which ends with "_Puliafito.docx" to the other directory.

Comment: Not all filesystem manipulation is created equal. Depending on the concrete implementation, some wildcards may or may not work. If this is actually Visual Basic **.NET**, no wildcards are supported at all.

Comment: Damned... it actually IS **.net** . Well, that's sad. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards don't automatically work everywhere – they must be expanded by the program itself. (It is primarily only shells and file managers which do. As @DanielB mentions VB may also do so but VB.NET does not. Neither do other programming environments.)

However, there usually *are* functions to expand wildcards – in .NET you have two:

- [Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [FileSystem.GetFiles(path, searchType, pattern)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127994(v=vs.110).aspx)

Use those on your pattern, receive an array of files, then move each file individually.

In other environments the function may be called [glob()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html).